# Jackson - Can't deserialize datetime with timezone offset 'unparsed text found at index 23'

Tags: java, spring, datetime, jackson, datetime-parsing

My datetime has to come from frontend with timezone offset: `2017-07-04T06:00:00.000+01:00`

I cannot deserialize it with Jackson.
The error is:

> Text '2017-07-04T06:00:00.000+01:00' could not be parsed, unparsed
>   text found at index 23;

I was trying to Google the solution by all are about DateTime with Z at the end.

```
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS aZ")
    private LocalDateTime time;
```

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: There is. You should probably give us the details about how the parsing was supposed to happen, maybe show us some code.

Comment: added the code, sorry

Comment: With next to no Jackson experience I’m probably shooting blindfolded: your string seems to match an `OffsetDateTime`, so what happens if you change your type to that and leave out the pattern?

Comment: Are Jackson patterns like `DateTimeFormatter` patterns? If so, should it be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`? (no space, no `a`)

Comment: @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private OffsetDateTime time;   Still not working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [pattern `a` is used to parse **AM/PM**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), which is not in the input `String`, that's why you get a parse error.

The input format matches an `OffsetDateTime`, which can be parsed with the respective [built-in formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), so you can use this formatter in a deserializer object and register it in the module. You must also remove the `JsonFormat` annotation from the field.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
LocalDateTimeDeserializer deserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, deserializer);
om.registerModule(module);
```

This will parse the input and convert it to a `LocalDateTime`. In the test I've made, the value of `LocalDateTime` was set to `2017-07-04T06:00`.

---

To control the output, you can either do:

```
om.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Which will output the `LocalDateTime` as `2017-07-04T06:00:00`, or you can use a custom formatter:

```
LocalDateTimeSerializer serializer = new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS a"));
module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, serializer);
```

The serializer above will output the field as `2017-07-04T06:00:00.000 AM`. Please note that the `Z` pattern will not work because a `LocalDateTime` has no timezone information and it can't resolve its offset - because when you deserialized to a `LocalDateTime`, the offset information in the input (`+01:00`) was lost.

---

Another alternative (without the need to configure the object mapper) is to use the correct pattern in the annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[xxx]")
private LocalDateTime time;
```

Note that I used the pattern `[xxx]` because the offset (`+01:00`) can be optional: when deserializing, this information is lost becase a `LocalDateTime` has no information about timezones and offsets, so when serializing this field won't be found - making the field optional (using `[]` delimiters) make it work for both deserialization and serialization.

This will deserialize the input `2017-07-04T06:00:00.000+01:00` and serialize to  `2017-07-04T06:00:00.000` (note that the optional offset is not used in serialization, as the `LocalDateTime` has no such information).

---

If you want different formats for deserialization and serialization, you can also create custom classes and anotate them in the field:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends LocalDateTimeDeserializer {
    public CustomDeserializer() {
        super(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }
}

public class CustomSerializer extends LocalDateTimeSerializer {
    public CustomSerializer() {
        super(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS a"));
    }
}

// in this case, don't use @JsonFormat
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime time;
```

This will use the format `2017-07-04T06:00:00.000+01:00` for deserialize and the format `2017-07-04T06:00:00.000 AM` to serialize.

Comment: would be nice if you could elaborate more how to really implement it as I am a little bit lost, but your solution looks good so I'd like to get know how to use it

Comment: The object mapper is used to serialize and deserialize. How are you doing the deserialization?

Comment: automatically with Jackson

Comment: so good. Made it in seperate file to make it reusable across whole project. Great!